# Editing the default wordpress search

Tags: wp-query, query, search, sql

My wordpress sites search function is not relaxed enough for my liking. I want it to match more items and be less strict.

How would i do this? I was thinking it would to do a pre-get posts filter but then im not sure how to modify the query